# Synchronous functions executing faster than their asynchronous counterparts?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Consider the below two snippets:

```js
const loop1NoPromise = () => {
    let i = 0
    for (i; i < 500000; i++) {}
}

const loop2NoPromise = () => {
    let i = 0
    for (i; i < 500000; i++) {}
}

const startNoPromise = () => {
    console.time('No promise')
  
    loop1NoPromise()
    loop2NoPromise()
  
    console.timeEnd('No promise')
}

startNoPromise()
```

```js
const loop1Promise = async () => {
    let i = 0
    for (i; i < 500000; i++) {}

    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve());
}

const loop2Promise = async () => {
    let i = 0
    for (i; i < 500000; i++) {}
  
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve());
}

const startPromise = async () => {
    console.time('With promise')

    await Promise.all([loop1Promise(), loop2Promise()])

    console.timeEnd('With promise')
}

startPromise()
```

I was wondering if delegating multiple functions that weren't intended to be `Promise`s to the browser's web APIs and then `await`ing them would increase performance in any way. Going into this experiment, I half expected `startPromise` to run a bit quicker than `startNoPromise` and the other half of me expected them to run +/- the same.

However, running the below snippets individually shows that `startNoPromise` is significantly faster than `startPromise`. What strange to me, is that if I merge these two snippets into one snippet, and then execute `startNoPromise` and `startPromise`, then they run more or less equally as fast... but running them individually shows a ~1ms difference in time, with `startNoPromise` clocking in consistently at around 2.245ms.

My question is why was my original logic flawed, that making non-promise functions into promises and outsourcing them to web APIs would make them run faster (because they would therefore be running asynchronously)? Also, why is the `Promise` version of these two functions executing at a slower speed than their synchronous counterparts?

Comment: Async functions use *cooperating multi-tasking*. They do not run *in parallel*. They can't. Only one thing can run at a time. Your two loops aren't yielding to each other; the first one that gets to run runs to completion, and then the other will run. Which makes it no different to the sync code, except that it has some additional overhead.

Comment: i would rather say your code runs "delayed" and not "asynchronous".

Comment: investigate web workers

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" with JavaScript is that everything runs in a single thread, ie, only one thing can be done at a time. Using promises for CPU bound problems (code that is limited by the CPU power) will actually make it slower. The reason for the slow down is that the API calls for the promises and managing the promises all take CPU overhead as well.

Another thing to note is that with CPU bound functions without any await these functions will run in serial (one after the other) anyway. Adding await on the other hand will just make it even slower since there will be more management overhead.

Promises are great for code where you have to wait on something to complete outside of the main process. Most often that will be io.

Answer (score 0):

Both snippets are synchoronous calculations.

Returning a promise does not make **previous** calculations to be "asynchronous": It just returns an object that represents an asyncronous result. That is an (in this case already resolved) promise.

In your second snipped, the code you add only wraps the result in a promise which resolution cannot be handled until next event loop cycle.

In other words: When you do `await Promise.all(...)` you are telling JS engine to attend all pending events and, in the next cycle, check if all promises are resolved and get its value or continue waiting otherwise and so on.

If you remove the *await* keyword you will see almost identical results.

You can also wrap the `Promise.all(...)` expression into a `console.log(...)` and you will see that value (a pending promise).